# ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an error when trying to post data to an api. Below is the code snippet. Looking forward for some help soon!Thanks

```java
String id= Comment.getId();
String authStr = "userName:password";
String base64Creds = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(authStr.getBytes());
// create headers
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds);
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
JSONObject commonJsonObject = new JSONObject();
commonJsonObject .put("body","password");
SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
// Connect timeout: time is in milliseconds
clientHttpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(3000);
// Read timeout: time is in milliseconds
clientHttpRequestFactory.setReadTimeout(3000);
HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(commentJsonObject.toString(), headers);
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory);
String newCommentString = restTemplate.postForObject(url, request, String.class);
```

> 7org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "jirasdtest.myoutotec.com/rest/api/2/issue/SD-1043/comment": connect timed out; nested exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:744) at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:670)

Comment: Post the stacktrace as well

Comment: 7org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://jirasdtest.myoutotec.com/rest/api/2/issue/SD-1043/comment": connect timed out; nested exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
 at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:744)
 at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:670)

Comment: What's the line where the exception occurs?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a choice of `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory` is not the best solution ...
Please try to use another implementation - `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory`:

```
var requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(20000);
requestFactory.setConnectionRequestTimeout(20000);
requestFactory.setReadTimeout(30000);
```

`SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory`:

> ClientHttpRequestFactory implementation that uses standard JDK
>   facilities.

`HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory`:

> ClientHttpRequestFactory implementation that uses Apache
>   HttpComponents HttpClient to create requests.

Comment: I guessed it worked, but how do I test it? I dont see any error in the console though